# JCommander and missing commands

Tags: java, jcommander

I am using JCommander 1.83.

I am using the command feature [documented here](https://jcommander.org/#_more_complex_syntaxes_commands).

My issue is that JCommander doesn't handle a blank command line the way I expect.  If I omit a command but provide other parameters, I get a MissingCommandException, as expected.  If I omit required parameters I get a ParameterException, as expected.  If I provide no input at all, I do not get an exception but probably should.  Obviously there is nothing to parse so my parameter object is empty.

```
public static final void main(String[] args) {
  Params params = new Params();
  JCommander jc = JCommander.newBuilder().addCommand(params).build();
  jc.parse(args);

  System.out.println(jc.getParsedCommand());  // will be null but I expected an exception by now
}

@Parameters(names = "xyz")
static class Params() {
  @Paramater(names="message")
  String message;
}
```